# IntelliJ toggle test not finding tests

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

In my java project for some reason, even though the class and the test class are located in the same package and the source directory for the tests is specified via the Project Settings -> Modules -> Test Directories, when I did Ctrl+Shift+T it says "No Test Class Found".

I think the reason is because we define everything as an interface, and the classes are all named InterfaceNameImpl and the tests as InterfaceNameContext. So when trying to toggle from InterfaceNameImpl it is looking for InterfaceNameImplTest rather than the correct class.

There is no way that this convention is going to be changed now so is there a way to make IntelliJ work with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no way that this convention is going to be changed now so is
>   there a way to make IntelliJ work with it?

No, it's hardcoded at the moment. You can [submit a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) to make it configurable.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this has changed in the last few years?